# String was not recognized as a valid datetime in the where statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, parsing, datetime

im using the folowing linq query to compare some dates, it's workin but when i change the system culture to en-US (i'm on french culture) it shows me the error
string was not recognized as a valid datetime in the where part, this is my query:

```
var query = 
    from Ovp c in lOvpReponse.result
     where (DateTime.parse(c.dateEcheance) >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))
        select new
        {
            RefDossier = c.refDossier,
            CompteEmetteur = c.compteEmetteur,
            NomBeneficiaire = c.nomBeneficiaire,
            Montant = c.montant,
            Periodicite = c.periodicite,
            status = DateTime.Parse(c.dateEcheance)>= DateTime.Now ? "Expiré" : "Activé",
        };
```

Hope to get some quick help here.

Comment: What is the value for `c.dateEcheance`? What is your current date time setting on your machine?

Comment: [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @PatrickHofman my current datime setting was french every thing was ok but when i moved the project to another machine that runs on en-US gave me this error and the date value format is 30/04/2034

Comment: Does the format of `c.dateEcheance` change when you change the culture?

Comment: @Marwie no it dosen't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the culture of your system, the `DateTime.Parse` method will change its behaviour and expect a datetime in the current systems format. You propably have this issue because the format of c.dateEcheance remains the same and therefore doesn't fit the now expected en-Us locale. You will have to explicitely add the Culture as parameter to the Parse method to parse it independend of your systems configuration.

Try this:

```
DateTime.Parse(c.dateEcheance, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

or this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateEcheance, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Comment: *Even if you change the culture, the format of c.dateEcheance will not change.* Duh, the format it is using to parse is...

Comment: @PatrickHofman With high chance a date in the french culture since he doesn't get the error then.

Comment: The culture is already French. Setting it explicitly to French doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @PatrickHofman to my understanding it is explicitely not French -> " it's workin but when i change the system culture to en-US (i'm on french culture) it shows me the error"

Comment: i need a parsing method to work in both cultures without forcing the date format to fench.

Comment: @Anass90 I don't understand your question, can you explain? The DateTime will be just a DateTime (culture independend). You are only telling the `Parse` method what kind of formatted string it has to expect.

Comment: @Marwie it's so easy to understand my code is working when i am on french culture (local machine) but when i run my project in a production server( runs under Us culture) it shows me String was not recognized as a valid datetime int the where statement

Comment: @Anass90 Did you try the solution, I offered? Did it work?

Comment: @Marwie the first one worked ! the second no, everything is good 10'x a bunch !

Answer (score 1):

I guess the service returns the date in the French locale. You can use the `fr-FR` locale or provide a specific format to parse with. Use [this overload of `DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime.Parse(c.dateEcheance, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Or:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(c.dateEcheance, "dd-MM-yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Comment: Did you use that in both cases?

Comment: the normal datetime.parse is working only for the french culture and i used the datetime.parseExact but i still have the same error when i move to Us culture